# Magento 2 - Secure site

Tags: magento2, backup

I would like to secure my magento 2 site, and to be sure to lose nothing.
If there is a problem, I can restore a backup but I will lose datas between now and the date of the backup.

Do you know how I can secure my site to have all datas if unexpected problem occur?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I think the Magento Backup functionality via CLI might be interesting for you:

```
magento setup:backup [--code] [--media] [--db]
```

You can run the command every night via cronjob for example.

See here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-backup.html

Another option would be to ask your hosting provider if they can set up a **nightly backup** for your database and files.